# Why static final int is used in android standard classes avoiding enum?

Tags: java, android, enums

In standart android classes `static final int` vars is used to represent different flags. For example, View visability flags:

```
/** @hide */
@IntDef({VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Visibility {}

/**
 * This view is visible.
 * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

/**
 * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
 * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;

/**
 * This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
 * purposes. Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;

/**
 * Mask for use with setFlags indicating bits used for visibility.
 * {@hide}
 */
static final int VISIBILITY_MASK = 0x0000000C;

private static final int[] VISIBILITY_FLAGS = {VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE};
```

Why developers avoid using `enum` in this case?

Comment: Either the code predates Java 5, or the developer chose to use static `int`(s) (possibly for bit fiddling).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Bit fiddling is sometimes the reason.  But the bigger reason is perf, enums are horribly implemented for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do it mainly for performance, as others have said. The main performance impact is the amount of memory they use.

I feel this is the best resource on the matter (from the horses mouth)
https://youtu.be/Hzs6OBcvNQE

I know a video is unusual here on SO but it is the most to the point resource on the matter.

A side point:
Though Enums are not performance optimised, most apps done in Android Studio should be fine if they use Progaurd to convert all enums at compile time to static final ints. I do this as I find Enums a little more expressive.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Fixed

Answer (score -2):

Because enums are expensive.  First, they're strings.  That means comparing two is a string compare and not an int compare, which can be many times the cost.  Secondly, they're objects.  Creating lots of small objects on a device with limited RAM is a great way to go OOM due to fragmentation, and each allocation costs time.  As such they're horrible for performance.

Really Java messed up when they designed enums-  they should never have been objects or strings.  Even server side performance oriented code avoids them in favor of ints.

Comment: "First, they're strings" -- no, they are Java classes. "That means comparing two is a string compare and not an int compare" -- no, it is an object identity comparison. "Creating lots of small objects on a device with limited RAM is a great way to go OOM due to fragmentation, and each allocation costs time" -- while true, creating lots of instances of an enum itself is the anti-pattern, not the enum itself. This is not significantly different from any other class, where creating lots of instances of it is the anti-pattern.

Comment: To be pedantic, yes they're classes with a string variable member. None of the rest of the post changes. They were a horrible design decision and using them is anti performance. Sun screwed up.

Comment: [Joshua Bloch](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/628663950389841920), who actually wrote some of this stuff, disagrees with you.